# J.W. Gray's monumental work notes on the formal theory of internal (2-)categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, 2-categories, internal-categories

In the book "Topos Theory" of Peter Johnstone (*Topos Theory, LMS Monographs no. 10. Academic, 1977*) one finds at page 41 in Chapter 2:

"For a detailed account of internal categories from a 2-categorical point of view, the reader is referred to the monumental work of JW Gray [168]."

The work of J.W. Gray has to be very important and significant (in those years Gray was one of the great masters of category theory) as well known and whose output is only the first part in *Formal Category Theory: Adjointness for 2-Categories. Series: Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol 391*.

Does anyone have news of such notes of J.W. Gray? Of course I would like to read these.

Comment: For everyone else: reference [168] from Johnstone is "Formal category theory II, To appear". 
@Buschi My advice is to look at work by Street, Kelly and Lack. I don't have proper references at the moment, I'm afraid. 'Tis late and I've got to get up early for prezzies :) At least look at Fibrations in bicategories by Street: http://archive.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1980__21_2_111_0.pdf

Comment: Why don't you write Gray? His information is at http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gray/ 

Comment: Did anything come of this, @Buschi?

Comment: I would like to second the question by @DavidRoberts (hopefully generating another notification).

Comment: It may also be worth contacting Peter Johnstone now, who may have a copy.

Comment: @varkor I tried emailing Gray asking about his notes around the middle of 2020, but I got a notification from the "UIUC mailer daemon" saying that the email failed to be delivered after 5 days and that Gray's email is "over quota". I'm not sure if this would still happen again today, but maybe it would be a good idea to write a letter (or send a fax!) to him instead.

Comment: @Emily maybe an email to the department head to double check on him?

Comment: @Emily: sadly [John Gray died in 2017](https://www.news-gazette.com/obituaries/john-gray/article_fb2520a5-d6c4-5087-9ac1-ed6613823b9a.html), so it is no longer possible to ask him about this work directly. (I don't know why his website hasn't been updated accordingly.)

Answer (score 8):

I asked Peter Johnstone about this citation, and he told me that he included the reference, despite not having a copy of the manuscript, since John Gray had been promising a book on the subject for many years, and he had expected that the book would appear soon. Unfortunately, it never did. It appears likely that any notes Gray might have made on the subject are now lost.

Comment: You can see why Johnstone decided on his hard "only actually published" policy for citations in The Elephant...